# how to get back the java UUID stored in DB as binary

Tags: java, mysql, database, string, jdbc

We have a Java UUID field that is stored in database (MySQL) as binary bytes after the following conversion

```
private byte[] getUUIDtoBytes(UUID devId) {
    byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(uuidBytes)
            .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
            .putLong(devId.getMostSignificantBits())
            .putLong(devId.getLeastSignificantBits());
    return uuidBytes;
```

And after retrieving it from DB using resultSet.getBytes, the byte array is converted back to UUID in the following way

```
private UUID toUUID(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    Long high = byteBuffer.getLong();
    Long low = byteBuffer.getLong();

    return new UUID(high, low);
}
```

This works fine until now I have to find the UUID field of a row in production. The application that displays the record probably uses the getText or getString to show the byte arrays and just by getting the byte array of the result string (with UTF-8) and applying my toUUID method, I cannot get back the UUID value of the record :(

Unfortunately, all the retrieval endpoints of our service require this UUID field. Can I have some hint on how I may possibly use the string format of that byte array, and convert it back to the original UUID?

Comment: Please highlight the code which is doing the UUID comparison, and ideally comment on why you think it is wrong.

Comment: "The application that displays the record probably uses the getText or getString to show the byte arrays" - What does the output look like? Are you aware that `byte[]` -> `String` -> `byte[]` is not lossless?

Comment: @JimmyB But careful...I'm not sure that the dashes of the UUID are actually part of the byte array.  So a direct string to byte array conversion might not work here.

Comment: Thank you all for the nice comments. I guess I didn't explain it well. My code of converting UUID to binary and binary back to UUID as above works fine, as long as it is using ResultSet getBytes and then the toUUID conversion. But another application (the only one that shows us production data without ops involvement) is using getText or getString to display the binaries is displaying it in the format of  'D}I´cL}»»JO'.  How can I get the original byte array out of this string and then use my toUUID to transform it back to the UUID? I tried String getBytes with UTF-8 and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert your UUID string into a bona fide `UUID` object via the `UUID#fromString()` method.  Then, you can compare the least and most significant bits fields of the two UUID which you have:

```
boolean UUIDIsEqual(UUID one, String twoInput) {
    UUID two = UUID.fromString(twoInput);
    if (one.getLeastSignificantBits() == two.getLeastSignificantBits() &&
        one.getMostSignificantBits() == two.getMostSignificantBits()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If, instead of having a `UUID` for the reference you have a byte array, then you can just use the `toUUID()` method which you already have to convert the string to a UUID.

Follow the link below for a demo showing that the string to UUID conversion works and is logically correct:

### Demo