# How to convert UUID column of dataframe into simple string containing the same hex sequence?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need to convert UUID columns of a dataframe into String columns which would have the same hex sequence eg. if a particular field has the following value:

```
JUUID("940bf38c-92d7-49fd-8ad0-67627c6b5084")
```

it should transform the column such that it gives an output of

```
"940bf38c-92d7-49fd-8ad0-67627c6b5084"
```

I printed out the schema and found that the column is coming as a struct:

```
 |-- resourceId: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- subType: byte (nullable = false)
 |    |-- data: binary (nullable = true)
```

which is why if I have the UDF defined as accepting an input of String, it's never getting called. How should I approach this problem?

### EDIT

Sorry I had no time to post code snippets yesterday. I have advanced somewhat after that and I am now giving my findings.

I was initially loading the Mongo documents using RDDs:

```
JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc);
```

Loading the first document as JSON:

```
System.out.println(rdd.first().toJson());
```

Outputs were like these:

```
"relativeId": {"$binary": "KUrqX+N+IP663myObpnOhA==", "$type": "03"}
```

From [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47751715/how-to-get-back-the-java-uuid-stored-in-db-as-binary), I got how to convert the binaries back to the hex format.

Now what I need to do is change the binaries inline to the proper hex format in the JSONs and write them back. I had gone the dataset way some time to see if I can use UDFs:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = rdd.toDF();

spark.sqlContext().udf().registerJava("UUIDTransformer", UUIDTransformer.class.getName(),
                DataTypes.StringType);

ds = ds.withColumn("resourceId2", functions.callUDF("UUIDTransformer", functions.col("resourceId")));
```

The UDF is as follows:

```
public class UUIDTransformer implements UDF1<GenericRowWithSchema, String> {



//  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String call(GenericRowWithSchema columnValue) throws Exception {


    System.out.println("Value of col: " + columnValue.toString());
    return "Successful";
}

}
```

The values were being printed, but they were not the same binary values as I had got when having them as JSONs from RDDs, and they could not also be converted back to hex, as they were giving exceptions that they were not a proper hex code. So I reverted back to RDDs.

But now the problem is how would I apply the changes inline to each such JUUID column, which sometimes are also nested within structs?

Comment: Can you provide some code to generate a sample of your input dataframe? Or at least, provide a sample of what the `show` methods prints?

Comment: @Oli, I have now given the code snippets of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To make the transformation inline, this is what I did:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
```

Using the UUID decode and encode program as I had found in the link mentioned in OP, I then went on to replace the existing UUID column using this code:

```
jsonObject.addProperty("resourceId", UUIDDecodeEncode
            .decompress(jsonObject.get("resourceId").getAsJsonObject().get("$binary").getAsString()).toString());
```

The resourceID column was coming as following in the original JSON from which I had to take out the encoded part:

```
"resourceId":{"$binary":"vEOsgXxlT7oX5rKoOAGRrA==","$type":"03"}
```