# Java Spark RDD operations not getting processed

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

This is in continuation of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59140110/how-to-convert-uuid-column-of-dataframe-into-simple-string-containing-the-same-h), but as this is a different issue, I thought it best to create a new question for it. I am having the following code:

```
JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc);
System.out.println("Count: " + rdd.count());

Gson gson = new Gson();
        rdd.foreach(item -> {
            String json = item.toJson();
//              JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
//              System.out.println(jsonObject.get("resourceId").getAsJsonObject().get("$binary").getAsString());
            Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
            }.getType());

            System.out.println(map.get("resourceId"));
            item.forEach((key, value) -> {
                if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("resourceId")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    resourceIds.add(value.toString());
                }
            });
        });
```

I have been trying to extract the information out of the JSON structure using Gson library, and strange thing is that yesterday, this code was giving me output. However, today, when I run a Spark submit job, the count is getting printed, but after that, the MongoConnection is getting closed and the job is falling silent. To first dissuade such assumptions, I'm declaring the Spark job to run with its master as local[3], so all logs would be printed in the driver console itself, not in any worker console.

```
2019-12-03 01:32:32 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - ResultStage 1 (count at UUIDTransformerEngine.java:209) finished in 2.707 s
2019-12-03 01:32:32 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 1 finished: count at UUIDTransformerEngine.java:209, took 2.711357 s
Count: 13716
2019-12-03 01:32:37 INFO  MongoClientCache:48 - Closing MongoClient:
```

The count also is giving me different results every time I run it, though the Mongo collection is not being edited. I have no idea how to bring the output back on, or what internal process of Spark is hindering the operation. Do I have to cache or something? Please shed some light on it.