# JOOQ Where clause using Oracle RAW type

Tags: java, oracle, blob, jooq

I'm trying to write a JOOQ query where it needs to search by UUID, which is stored in the Oracle database as RAW type.  In Jooq generated entities these type of fields are defined as byte array.

Simply converting the string to byte array does not find the matching value:
`jooqQuery.addConditions(TABLE.UUID_COLUMN.eq(UUID_AS_STRING).getBytes()));`

On the other hand when casting a column name to String:

`jooqQuery.addConditions(TABLE.UUID_COLUMN.cast(String.class).eq(UUID_AS_STRING));`

produces jdbc exception at runtime:

`"class":"o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","rest":"ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis\n"`

Is there a right way to cast this to produce a valid sql that work properly?

EDIT: I have also tried using `TABLE.UUID_COLUMN.getDataType().convert(UUID_AS_STRING)` The resulting query is identical to just doing getBytes() with the same empty search result

SOLVED: Using this method, converts UUID to correct byte array:

```
    private byte[] getUUIDtoBytes(UUID devId) {
        byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];
        ByteBuffer.wrap(uuidBytes)
                .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
                .putLong(devId.getMostSignificantBits())
                .putLong(devId.getLeastSignificantBits());
        return uuidBytes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you've stored your UUID as `uuid.getBytes()`. Calling `String.getBytes()` will yield the unicode encoding of the string, which would be a wasteful way to store a UUID, which is already in hexadecimal format. [A more likely encoding is documented in this SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47751715/521799).

In any case, you should find out how your UUID value was stored and encoded, and reuse that encoding mechanism. With jOOQ, ideally, you would attach a data type binding or converter to your `UUID_COLUMN`, such that you will never have to think about this again in any jOOQ query. More information about this here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

Comment: Thank you Lukas! Your first link included the conversion to appropriate encoding conversion to byte array.  Custom data type bindings seems promising for building some common conversion mechanisms across all domain systems.